# What is the best place to add AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayerController in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, avplayer, mpmovieplayercontroller

I try to play video in `UITableViewCell` when a user clicks on play button in cell.

Comment: batter option is that to play video open new controller on button click in cellrowatIndexpath

Comment: Just for your Information and adding in above comment: MPMoviePlayerController has been deprecated in iOS 9. Also look at this example https://github.com/Gagan5278/TableCellStreaming

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya, i want to play video in cell.

Comment: @Pankil if you want to play video in cell then you have to use avplayer and in cellrowatindexpath

Answer (score 10):

**Scene 1:**

If you are willing to auto play video's like Facebook or Instagram in each cell then consider adding `AVPlayer` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

`AVPlayer` will not allow you to change the url being played (`AVURLAsset` url) once created. So If you are using `AVPlayer` and providing ur own view to player I afraid creating `AVPlayer` instance every time in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is the only solution.

On the other hand if you are planning to use `AVPlayerViewController`, you can create `AVPlayer` `viewController` instance in cell's `awakeFromNib` so you will have only one instance of player per cell and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can pass different url each time. You can use prepareForReuse method of cell to pause the player and resetting all your player properties.

**Scene 2:**

If you are planning to play once user taps on button in cell, consider creating `AVPlayer`/`AVPlayerViewController` on button tap and play the video. Use `prepareForReuse` to reset the properties of ur player to ensure you don't play wrong video when u scroll and cell gets reused.

**EDIT:**

As OP has asked for some code snippet, providing skeleton code. This is not a copy paste code, idea is just to give idea of how to use `AVPlayerViewController` inside cell the code might have compiler issues.

//create a custom `tableViewCell` subclass

```
class ImageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var carsImageView: UIImageView!
    var playerController : AVPlayerViewController? = nil
    var passedURL : URL! = nil

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func configCell(with url : URL) {
        //something like this
        self.passedURL = url
        //show video thumbnail with play button on it.
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func playOrPauseVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        playerController.player = player
        playerController?.showsPlaybackControls = true
        playerController.player.play()
        //add playerController view as subview to cell
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        //this way once user scrolls player will pause
        self.playerController.player?.pause()
        self.playerController.player = nil
    }
}
```

The code above sets the `PlayerController` to nil in `prepareForReuse()` so when user scrolls the `tableView` and cell goes out of `tableView` Frame and gets reused, player will pause and will not retain the status. If you simply want to pause and replay when user scrolls back to the same cell u will have to save player somewhere outside the cell and find a way to map player instance to cell.

Finally in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` call,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : ImageTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageCell") as! ImageTableViewCell
    cell.configCell(with: URL(string: "https://google.com")!)
    ....
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

As OP has completely filped the question to play only one video at any point in time and pause other playing videos on tapping play button my earlier answer will no longer hold true.

Earlier answer allows user to play multiple video.

Here is a modified answer to make it work.

Modify your custom cell class as below.

```
protocol VideoPlayingCellProtocol : NSObjectProtocol {
    func playVideoForCell(with indexPath : IndexPath)
}

class ImageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var carsImageView: UIImageView!
    var playerController : AVPlayerViewController? = nil
    var passedURL : URL! = nil
    var indexPath : IndexPath! = nil
    var delegate : VideoPlayingCellProtocol = nil

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func configCell(with url : URL,shouldPlay : Bool) {
        //something like this
        self.passedURL = url
        if shouldPlay == true {
            let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            if self.playerController == nil {
                playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
            }
            playerController.player = player
            playerController?.showsPlaybackControls = true
            playerController.player.play()
        }
        else {
            if self.playerController != nil {
                self.playerController.player?.pause()
                self.playerController.player = nil
            }
            //show video thumbnail with play button on it.
        }
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func playOrPauseVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate.playVideoForCell(self.indexPath)
        //add playerController view as subview to cell
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        //this way once user scrolls player will pause
        self.playerController.player?.pause()
        self.playerController.player = nil
    }
}
```

In your TableView VC create a property called

```
var currentlyPlayingIndexPath : IndexPath? = nil
```

Make your TableView VC to confirm VideoPlayingCellProtocol

```
extension ViewController : VideoPlayingCellProtocol {
    func playVideoForCell(with indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.currentlyPlayingIndexPath = indexPath
    //reload tableView
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none)
   }
}
```

Finally modify your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : ImageTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageCell") as! ImageTableViewCell
        //delegate setting here which u missed
        cell.delegate = self
        //let the cell know its indexPath
        cell.indexPath = indexPath

            cell.configCell(with: URL(string: "https://google.com")!, shouldPlay: self.currentlyPlayingIndexPath == indexPath)
        ....
}
```

Thats all you need.

Comment: i prefered Scene 2 and i updated my question with button click event code. as you suggest to use 'prepareForReuse' how to use it?

Comment: @pankil : Create a AVPlayerViewController instance inside a cell. Don't create it in tableView Controller and add it as subview. Let the cell create its own player instance so it will have access to it always. override prepareForReuse inside you custom cell class, pause the player/remove the player based on your need. Remove all the observers you have added to the player. So when cell gets reused it will be a plain cell as it was first time.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, Thanks for your help. i initialize AVPlayerViewController in my cell. like in above code. can you provide example with cellforrow and player initialization in cell?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, When to call playOrPauseVideo method?

Comment: @pankil : Its a IBAction. I believe u have a play button on video thumbnail in cell initially and then when user taps on play button it plays the video

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, is it possible for you to review my code?

Comment: @pankil : Now you have changed your requirement all together buddy :( You never said there should only be one video playing all the time. My code allows you to play multiple videos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146028/discussion-between-pankil-and-sandeep-bhandari).

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, i put those 3 methods in MyCell.m
1. configureCell 2. prepareForReuse 3. playPauseVideo and than . i call configureCell from cellForRowAtIndexPath and playPauseVideo from button tap
but i play 1 video, it plays and when i scroll previously played video preview display in other cell

Comment: @pankil : In configCell update your ImageView buddy so that It won't show the preview of previously played video thats all. Hope U are getting what am saying u need a imageView,button and player in cell. In Prepare for reuse you clear the player and in configCell method all update ur imageView :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, i call playOrPauseVideo on cell button tap, it will not play video. I implement delegate & VideoPlayingCellProtocol in my TableView VC but method not getting called.

Comment: @pankil : delegate not getting called because u never passed any delegate object to cell buddy :) gimme a minute lemme update answer

Comment: @pankil : Please look at cell.delegate = self in my answer :) And why is it not playing in button tap is your player view controller nil ? Please debug :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, it's my mistake to forgot to write cell.delegate = self. My question is that when i click play button it will call delegate method. but indexpath is always nil

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, When i click on button, it will call [self.delegate playVideoForCell:self.indexPath]; where indexPath is nil & than after it will call TableView VC delegate Method -(void)playVideoForCell:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.currentlyPlayingIndexPath = indexPath;
} Where both indexpath are nil.  When indexPath is changed?

Comment: @pankil :Can u please check know 2 changes 1.cell.indexPath = indexPath in cell for row at index path and 2.self.tableView.reloadRows in playVideoForCell

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, thanks for ur help. now it will play clicked button video. for remain cell button state as it is while scrolling, i add tapped object in array and in cellForRow i check object is available in array than button is selected or not. is is possible to stop other all video when new cell button tapped?

Comment: @pankil : Have u overriden prepareForReuse? the whole purpose of prepareForReuse is to stop playing when cell gets reused. Finally we reload tableView's cells in visible range because configCell will be called on all cell and this time excluding the cell on which u tapped to play video for other cells all return shouldPlay value as false which should make them stop playing video.. So u have it excluding the cell u tapped other cells stops playing. What am I missing here ?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, 1 video is playing and when i scroll, playing video play in another cell and original video cell not play. I added player like this : self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player1];
        self.playerLayer.frame = self.playerView.bounds;
        self.playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
        AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
        playerViewController.player = player1;
        [playerViewController.player play];
        [self.playerView.layer addSublayer:self.playerLayer];

Comment: @pankil : Put a break point in PrepareForReuse() and check the code execution

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, i write this code in prepareForReuse() [self.playerViewController.player pause];
    self.playerViewController.player = nil; but the AVPlayerViewcontroller is not nil.

Comment: @pankil : Try setting that nil

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, not working , still current playing layer display on different cell while scrolling. can you pls look to my code?

Comment: @pankil : I cant see it right now Ill see it in sometime

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, np. i update dropbox code with latest code that you suggest. when u free pls review code and tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, hi sandeep, pls suggest me to solve this issue.

Comment: @pankil : Sorry buddy little busy with todays release. Ill look into ur code this weekend and will let u know

Comment: @SandeepBhandari your code has some typo in Edit 1. You haven't used passedURL when creating player with URL.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari can you help me out in this ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787983/autoplay-video-in-uitableviewcell-hiccupps

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar requirement as you and created global `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerLayer` variables in my `UITableViewController`. I then attached them to a cell when a person selected the cell.  From what I've seen, my scrolling is smooth, memory usage is minimal, and it also enforces that only one video is played at a time.

First step was to create the variables in my `UITableViewController`:

```
lazy var avPlayer : AVPlayer = {
    let player = AVPlayer()
    return player
}()

lazy var avPlayerLayer : AVPlayerLayer = {
    let layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.avPlayer)
    return layer
}()
```

I then created two functions in the `UITableViewController` to handle linking and removing the `AVPlayerLayer` from a cell as such.

```
private func removePlayerFromCell()
{
    if (self.avPlayerLayer.superlayer != nil)
    {
        self.avPlayerLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        self.avPlayer.pause()
        self.avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
    }
}

private func attachPlayerToCell(indexPath : IndexPath)
{
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    {
        self.removePlayerFromCell()

        //create url
       let url = ... 

        //create player item
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        self.avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)

        self.avPlayerLayer.frame = cell.contentView.frame
        cell.contentView.layer.addSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer)

        self.avPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

You can then call `attachPlayerToCell()` in `didSelectRowAt()`.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    attachPlayerToCell(indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

Lastly, to ensure videos don't play during scrolling, use the table's `UIScrollViewDelegate` to stop playback:

```
override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.removePlayerFromCell()
}
```

Hope this helps and is clear.